# how to subtract within pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question on arithmetic within a dataframe. Please note that each of the below columns in my dataframe are based on one another except for 'holdings'

Here is a shortened version of my dataframe

```
'holdings' & 'cash' & 'total'
0.0           10000.0   10000.0
0.0           10000.0   10000.0
1000          9000.0    10000.0
1500          10000.0   11500.0
2000          10000.0   12000.0

initial_cap = 10000.0
```

But here is my problem... the first time I have holdings, the cash is calculated correctly where cash of 10000.0 - holdings of 1000.0 = 9000.0

I need cash to remain at 9000.0 until my holdings goes back to 0.0 again
Here are my calculations

In other words, how would you calculate cash so that it remains at 9000.0 until holdings goes back to 0.0

Here is how I want it to look like

```
'holdings' & 'cash' & 'total'
0.0           10000.0   10000.0
0.0           10000.0   10000.0
1000          9000.0    10000.0
1500          9000.0   10500.0
2000          9000.0   11000.0
```

cash = initial_cap - holdings

Comment: Please clarify your question. For example, is your dataframe called `portfolio`? what does each entry in your dataframe represent? How are `holdings`, `cash`, and `total` calculated? Since you appear to use `positions['positions_diff']` and `data['close']` to calculate `portfolio['cash']`, more information on those might also be helpful.

Comment: Agreed, please explain more thoroughly what you want to do.

Comment: hi guys, sorry for the ambiguity. I have edited my original post. I am trying to simplify it down to the calculation itself. Ignoring how the rest is calculated... I hope this helps.

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to achieve. What data is provided to you and what do you need to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

So I try to rephrase: You start with initial capital `10` and a given sequence of holdings `{0, 0, 1, 1.5, 2}` and want to create a cashvariable that is `10` whenever `cash` is `0`. As soon as `cash` increases in an initial period by `x`, you want cash to be `10 - x` until cash equals `0` again.

If this is correct, this is what I would do (the logic of total and all of this is still unclear to me, but this is what you added in the end, so I focus on this).

PS. Providing code to create your sample is considered nice

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3], columns=['holdings'])
x = 10
# triggers are when cash is supposed to be zero
triggers = df['holdings'] == 0
# inits are when holdings change for the first time
inits = df.index[triggers].values + 1
df['cash'] = 0
for i in inits:
    df['cash'][i:] = x - df['holdings'][i]
df['cash'][triggers] = 0
df
Out[339]: 
   holdings  cash
0         0     0
1         1     9
2         2     9
3         2     9
4         0     0
5         2     8
6         3     8
7         3     8
```

Comment: i will definitely give this a try. here is the logic: total = cash + holdings .... but my cash needs to remain the same once holdings changes from 0.0 to a value.

Comment: Then you can just compute total in the end through a simple addition of columns once everything else is calculated.

Comment: how would that work exactly? can you show me a sample equation.. really appreciate it

Comment: `df['total'] = df['cash'] + df['holdings']` will do a column wise addition. Pretty straightforward. Don't forget to close the question once you got it :)